# A simle Perl code with here-document works on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: windows, string, perl, heredoc

While practicing I found that the following code is working fine on Linux but not on Windows

```
print<<EOF;
this is a paragraph
EOF
```

On Windows it says.

> Can't find string terminator "EOF" anywhere before EOF at demo.pl.

Comment: Does your file have the right line ends? Linux: LF, Windows CR+LF

Comment: yes i checked that it is having right line ends

Comment: And... Is there a line end at end of file?

Comment: yes it is there.just now i tried the same code by creating the file using copy con cmmand and it worked fine.but not working with file created using notepad

Comment: Then it seems that your windows perl does not understand windows line ends and needs linux line ends.

Comment: What says online `demo.pl` dump? http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm

Comment: Basically just 4 possibilities.  There's spacing before the EOF token.  There's spacing after the EOF token.  There is no line terminator at that line.  Or the line terminators are the wrong format, unix versus windows.

Comment: what perl are you using?  cygwin?

Comment: @ysth i am using active perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows thinks the end of file is part of the terminating string `EOF`, thus it doesn't follow the rule that The terminating string must appear by itself. You need to add a new line after the terminating string `EOF`.

```
print<<EOF;
this is a paragraph
EOF
# a new line
```

Comment: @nikhilmehta It works on my machine(Perl v5.16.3, Windows 7 64-bit)

Comment: @nikhilmehta I'm using Active Perl, I wonder if this makes a difference.